# is there any way to validate if two compound index fields already exist in a many-to-many table?

Tags: php, laravel

For example here I am inserting the fields question_id, query_id, sub_test_id, test_id, score and answer. the question_id and query_id fields are unique index, how can I validate if when inserting these two fields they already exist in the table?

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
                $query->getQuestions()->attach($questions[$i]->id, [
                    'score' => $scores[$i], 'answer' => $answers[$i],
                    'sub_test_id' => $section->id, 'test_id' => $section->getTest->id
                ]);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are having some troubles when you are attaching something and the entry inside the pivot table already exists.

The solution is to use `syncWithoutDetaching` instead of `attach`.

`syncWithotuDetaching` uses a different syntax, take a look:

```php
$query->getQuestions()->syncWithoutDetaching([
    $questions[$i]->id => [
        'score' => $scores[$i], 
        'answer' => $answers[$i],
        'sub_test_id' => $section->id, 
        'test_id' => $section->getTest->id
    ]
]);
```

If something is already there, nothing will change except the additional data (in your exemple, `score` would be updated).

If there is no link between your resources, it will be created.

You can think of `syncWithoutDetaching` as "update or create" for many to many relationships.

Comment: Ok I tried, I no longer get the error of duplicate keys, but it does not update me the additional data that is inserted as score and answers. it is practically as if I did nothing, the data does not change.

Comment: I updated my answer so it works with `syncWithoutDetaching`. Sorry for the mistake, it should be good now.

Comment: The idea is to give `syncWithoutDetaching` an array of arrays where each key represent a question id and each value the question's data (score., answer...)